# Why Does FireFox Trigger OnMessage() sometimes and does not trigger the other time, while using FCM

Tags: firebase, firefox, firebase-cloud-messaging

While Using FCM when a notification is send against token for firefox browser , the messaging.onMessage function gets called sometimes and not for the other times.
I really Can't Understand what is the issue
My JS Code is:-

```
var config = {
            apiKey: "my api key",
            authDomain: "my auth domain",
            databaseURL: "my db url",
            projectId: "my proj id",
            storageBucket: "my stirage bucket url",
            messagingSenderId: "my msging sender ID"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);


    var messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        messaging.getToken()
        .then(function(token){
            console.log(token)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Unable to generate Token')
        })
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    })

    messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
        console.log(payload.notification.body);
    })
```

my json for notification is:-

{
    "notification": {
        "title": "My Title",
        "body": "My Message",
        "icon": "",
        "click_action": ""
    },
    "to": "token"
}

Comment: Is the browser *always* in the foreground (visible and in focus) when receiving the notifications?